# Let $A = J_n (\lambda)$ be a $n \times n$ Jordan block. Determine the Jordan form of $A^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Let $A = J_n(\lambda)$ be a $n \times n$ Jordan Block. Determine the Jordan form of $A^k$.

How to approach the problem? Need some hints

$A = J_n(\lambda) = J_n(0) + \lambda I$. Now $A^k = {(J_n(0) + \lambda I)}^k $ and the expansion follows the binomial expansion. Will this be any need?

Comment: Jordon $\to$ Jordan.

Comment: i cant understand can you explain a little bit

Comment: It is just a spelling remark : "a" instead of "o".

Comment: so how to do it? any hints?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Continuing with your suggestion, your expression with the Binomial Theorem gives
$$J_n(\lambda)^k = (J_n(0) + \lambda I_n)^k = \sum_{i = 0}^k {k \choose i} \lambda^{k - i} J_n(0)^i .$$
Now, since $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue of $J_n(\lambda)^k$, the only eigenvalue of $J_n(\lambda)^k$ is $\lambda^k$. Thus, the Jordan form of $J_n(\lambda)^k$ is some direct sum of Jordan blocks $J_{n_a}(\lambda^k)$, and it remains just to determine what the block sizes $n_a$ are.

As usual, we can determine these sizes by analyzing the dimensions of the kernels of the powers of 
$$J_n(\lambda)^k - \lambda^k I_n .$$
Glancing back at our expansion of the first term we see that $\lambda^k I_n$ is precisely the first term in the sum, so this difference is just
$$\sum_{i = 1}^k {k \choose i} \lambda^{k - i} J_n(0)^i$$
(NB this sum begins at index $i = 1$, and that it is empty in the special case $k = 0$, which is anyway trivial.)

> **Additional hint** Notice that since $J_n(0)$ is strictly upper triangular, the last entry of $$\sum_{i = 1}^k {k \choose i} \lambda^{k - i} J_n(0)^i {\bf x}$$ is $0$, and, for example, the second-to-last entry is $k \lambda^{k - 1} x_n$. This suggests, among other things, splitting into the cases $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda \neq 0$.

Comment: I will delete my answer, as this one is far better (and mine doesn't solve it all the way)
Loved the way you solved it.

Comment: I thought your answer was fine, and OP might anyway well prefer the explicit matrix formula you gave---in that way, it was complimentary to this one. (And for that matter, this answer [deliberately] doesn't fully solve the problem either.) Anyway, thank you!